# How to import python package on OS level so that it can be re use

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, import, operating-system

I am using python as a shell and sending request to python in a loop but inside python script i am importing some package e.g. tensorflow, imutils etc and when python script boot for execution it's taking too much time(because its first importing all packages and then start execution), time for one import see below:

```
time python -c "import tensorflow.compat.v1"

real   0m2.680s

user   0m2.974s

sys    0m0.752s
```

and when this shell script is running in loop every time it is importing packages and doing processing, there is any way so that i can import all packages once and use again and again.

Note: For creating shell using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

Please help me if any one having solution.

Comment: You probably want to run that python file as a process, let it initialize and then provide a function / service to do whatever you need done that is externally callable.  Then instead of loading the whole script from the loop you just call the service to calculate what you need and you don't reload the packages every time.  Sorry if that sounds complicated but there is no "pre-load Python packages at the system level", so that's a flat no to your question.  Google as *Python JS microservice*, this type of architecture is very popular right now.

Comment: Thanks @JLPeyret i was thinking the same and i am going to try the same architecture using socket based connection and spawn a task and push that to already running script.